# Default argument promotion in a variadic function

Tags: c, language-lawyer

The meanings of the phrases *trailing arguments* and *default argument promotion* are unclear to me as used in the following excerpts, where the two paragraphs seem almost contradictory, leading me to be unclear about when default promotions should be expected.

[ISO/IEC 9899:201x](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1539.pdf) section *6.5.2.2 Function calls*:

- para 6: *If  the  expression  that  denotes  the  called  function  has  a  type  that  does  not  include  a prototype,..., and arguments  that have  type `float` are  promoted  to `double`.  These  are  called  the* default argument promotions.
- para 7: *"...The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter.  The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments."*

From paragraph 6, (*a  type  that  does  not  include  a prototype*) seems to suggest that only arguments `4.0` and `5.0` will undergo default promotions.  Then in para. 7 it says promotion stops after the last declared parameter.  (I believe that is `b`). Seeming to suggest that `a` and `b` will undergo promotions, but nothing following them in the argument list will be promoted.  But then it goes on to say default promotions are performed on trailing arguments.  Trailing means *at the end of*, indicating those allowed by the ellipsis.

So what exactly gets promoted when calling f(), and Why?

```
 int f(float a, float b, ...);
 
 int main(void)
 {
     float a = 1.0;
     float b = 2.0;

     int res = f(a, b, 4.0, 5.0);
     return 0;
 }

 int f(float a, float b, ...)
 {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: para 7 says "argument type conversion" stops (according to the prototype  I assume), not "promotion stops". I think that's a difference

Comment: The arguments `4.0` and `5.0` are both of type `double` and undergo no promotion.  Paragraph 7 says that the normal conversion of actual argument type to the type demanded by the prototype stops when there are no more named parameters because the arguments are passed 'to the ellipsis' part of the function signature.  If you passed `1.0` in place of `a`, then the `double` value would be converted to `float` because of the prototype (assuming `f` was declared correctly before it was called).  If you passed `4.0F` instead of `4.0`, the `float` value would be default promoted to `double`.

Comment: I considered the two phrases synonymous, i.e. doesn't _argument type conversion_ mean converting from eg. `float` to `double`?

Comment: "argument type conversion" means converting to the declared type of the corresponding parameter. "default argument promotion" refers to converting to a default type because there's no declared parameter.

Comment: No — the phrases are different because they mean different things.  Argument type conversion is the process that allows `sqrt(2)` to work correctly — converting the integer argument to `double` because of the prototype.  Default argument promotions occur when there is no prototype or when the argument is passed 'to the ellipsis' part of a prototyped function.

Comment: If I read this correctly, your excerpt from 6 relates to function calls *without* a known prototype, while 7 related to those *with* a prototype.

Comment: @Barmar I assumed there was a prototype declared earlier, otherwise the function call would be invalid.

Comment: @ryyker Please clarify the code regarding the scope of the declaration of `f()`.

Comment: @IanAbbott - _has a type that does not include a prototype_, I assumed this was referring to the variables be called, i.e. the arguements 3 and 4 in the example.

Comment: @IanAbbott - scope in file global.  Will edit.

Comment: @ryyker No, it's talking about the prototype of the function. It's distinguishing K&R function declarations from ANSI declarations.

Comment: Do you have a prototype `int f(float, float, ...);` before `main`?

Comment: @Barmar - just edited in  response to comments . Yes.  But am unclear on why that makes a difference.  does the phrase _If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype_ not refer non prototyped variable, i.e. those allowed by the ellipsis ?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - _The arguments 4.0 and 5.0 are both of type double and undergo no promotion_.  Even though the prototype explicitly says `float`?  (I also saw your statement _If you passed 4.0F instead of 4.0, the float value would be default promoted to double_ )

Comment: "the expression that denotes the called function" means the identifier `f`.

Comment: For example, in `(foo->bar)(a, b, c, d)`, "the expression that denotes the called function" is `(foo->bar)` and has nothing to do with the arguments of the function call _per se_.

Comment: @IanAbbott - Thank for that clarification.  It was central to my confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the conditions in Paragraph 6 apply to your example. A function without a prototype refers to a function declared using the archaic K&R syntax:

```
int f();
```

When you call a function with this type of declaration, all arguments undergo default promotions.

Paragraph 6 also describes other situations where there's a prototype and the types in the call are not compatible to with the types in the prototype, but your types are compatible (they're the same).

Paragraph 7 says that argument conversion is performed for the first two arguments; they're converted to `float` as specified in the prototype. Since `a` and `b` are already `float`, no conversion is necessary.

The remaining arguments undergo default argument promotion (as described in Paragrah 6), since they correspond to the ellipsis in the prototype. The literals `4.0` and `5.0` have type `double`, so no promotion is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding prototype or no prototype.   I had been assuming that the text _If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype,_ referred to the variables allowed by the ellipsis.  (i.e. arguments 3 and 4 in the example code. )

Comment: "expression that denotes the called function" refers to `f`.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated to clarify that none of the other conditions in 6 apply, either.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C11 standard [§6.5.2.2 Function calls](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2) (and I don't think this changed in C18), the full quotes for paragraphs 6 and 7 are:

> ¶6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the *default argument promotions.* If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the behavior is undefined. If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (`, ...`) or the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined. If the function is defined with a type that does not include a prototype, and the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with those of the parameters after promotion, the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> - one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
> - both types are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of a character type or void.
>
> ¶7 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

Given the code from the question:

```c
int f(float a, float b, ...);
 
int main(void)
{
    float a = 1.0;
    float b = 2.0;

    int res = f(a, b, 4.0, 5.0);
    return 0;
}

int f(float a, float b, ...)
{
     ...
}
```

There are no argument type conversions or promotions in the call to `f`.

- The arguments `a` and `b` are both of type `float`, the same as in the prototype and definition of the function, so there is no conversion required.
- The arguments `4.0` and `5.0` are both of type [`double`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.2p4) and do not undergo default argument promotion.  These values are passed after the last declared parameter, so they are eligible for default argument promotion, but since the type is already `double`, no promotion is required.
- If the argument was `4.0F` instead of `4.0`, then the `float` value would undergo default argument promotion to `double`.

If the call was written as:

```
int res = f(4.0, 5.0, a, b);
```

then:

- The `double` arguments `4.0` and `5.0` would be "implicitly converted, as if by assignment" to `float` because that's what the prototype requires.
- The `float` arguments `a` and `b` would be promoted to type `double` because they undergo default argument promotion.

Comment: One question, toward the bottom of your answer you say _The double arguments 4.0 and 5.0-  Did you mean _The `float` arguments 4.0 and 5.0_?

Comment: I meant "the `double` arguments `4.0` and `5.0`".  Without a qualifying suffix, floating point constants are of type `double`.  To create a `float` constant, add the suffix `F` (or `f`); to create a `long double` constant, add the suffix `L` (or `l`, but don't use the lower-case letter for either suffix).